# Is execCommand stable?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, rte

im trying to make a rich text editor with execCommand and a div that is contenteditable.

It should have some small functionalities like bold, italic, underline, ol, ul, ... All those things should work with execCommand. 
I also wanna have feedback from my cursor when i am standing in a bold word, that my button toggles to 'on' (changes styling), i do this with queryCommandState.

I have encountered numerous bugs and problems and i was wondering if execCommand and queryCommandState are stable? On caniuse.com they say it is but i've come across the following bugs:

In Chrome:

- No feedback on subscript and superscript

In Firefox:

- When making something italic or underline or ... the cursor cant move in that particular part of the string. This doesn't happen when i make a text bold.
- ordered and unordered list doesnt seem to work at all in firefox. the bullet is shown but cant enter any text

In Internet Explorer:

- Cant select any text

I'm probably forgetting some bugs, but my overall experience with execCommand and queryCommandState is that it's pretty buggy.
Is execCommand something to consider for apps that go in production? Or is it generally discouraged?

Comment: Not terribly on topic, but writing a high quality rich text editor on the web is _very_ _very_ hard. Unless this is just a project for fun, I'd strongly encourage you to look at using http://ckeditor.com/.

Comment: Yes i am aware of that. But with execCommand and queryCommandState it looks like you can make a very basic RTE. Too bad it's so buggy. Thanks for the response though!